# Convert SQL row into XML tag with value and attibutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a simple flat SQL table with three columns A, B and C:

```
CREATE TABLE [tmp]
(
  [A] NVARCHAR(32) NULL
, [B] NVARCHAR(32) NULL
, [C] NVARCHAR(32) NULL
);
```

I would like to convert each row to an XML object like

```
<Parameter name="A" description="B">666</Parameter>
```

If I use `FOR XML AUTO`, all columns are converted to an `XML` attribute. I can use `FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS` or use `FOR XML RAW` to get tags instead, but I would like to convert columns `A` and `B` to an attribute and use column `C` as the tag value.

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In almost all cases `FOR XML PATH` is the best approach (and the fastest)

```
CREATE TABLE [tmp]
(
  [A] NVARCHAR(32) NULL
, [B] NVARCHAR(32) NULL
, [C] NVARCHAR(32) NULL
);
INSERT INTO [tmp] VALUES
 ('A','B','666')
,('One more A','And one more B','777');

SELECT A AS [@name]
      ,B AS [@description]
      ,C AS [*]
FROM [tmp]
FOR XML PATH('Paramter');


--Clean Up
GO
DROP TABLE [tmp];
```

The result

```
<Paramter name="A" description="B">666</Paramter>
<Paramter name="One more A" description="And one more B">777</Paramter>
```

Comment: Excellent! I have tried a few special characters, but not the asterix! Thank you very much!